# How can I make Backends for reset password from auth lib

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

in reset password form, from auth lib, It has conditions that must be more than 8 characters and ..

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name = "account/forget/password_reset_form.html"), name ='password_reset_confirm'),
```

how can i make backends to save password immediately, No auth conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is checked by the *password validators*. The list of validators is specified by the [**`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS).

You thus can set the validators to the empty list:

```
# settings.py

# …

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = []

# …
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation) lists a set of validators that you can use to validate the password. In new projects, by default it will perform four types of validation:

> - **`UserAttributeSimilarityValidator`**, which checks the similarity between the password and a set of attributes of the user.
> - **`MinimumLengthValidator`**, which checks whether the password meets a minimum length. This validator is configured with a custom
>   option: it now requires the minimum length to be nine characters,
>   instead of the default eight.
> - **`CommonPasswordValidator`**, which checks whether the password occurs in a list of common passwords. By default, it compares to an
>   included list of 20,000 common passwords.
> - **`NumericPasswordValidator`**, which checks whether the password isn’t entirely numeric.

Comment: I put it empty but it doesn't work also, There are still conditions

Comment: @mehran281: but is there another list of validators defined. By default there is already a `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` in the `settings.py`.